# Visual studio minimizes form application and shows console window

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a problem with visual studio 2012. I recently opened a windows forms application I made a year ago for school.
But now when I ran it, it opens the Forms window minimized and out of nowhere it opens a black console window, I'm saying black because there's no data in it.

Did I perhaps accidently change something in the settings?

Comment: go to project properties and check output type dropdown and verify whether you have set Windows Application or Console Application ?

Comment: We can't smell if you accidentally changed something in the settings..

Comment: @Kurubaran the output type is set to console application.

Comment: @VascovanderEng Change it to Windows Application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `project properties` and check output type dropdown and verify whether you have set `Windows Application` or `Console Application` ?

[image]

Comment: I just changed it and now the console is gone. But forms is still minimized.

Comment: @VascovanderEng open your start up Windows Form and go to properties and make sure Windows State is set to "Normal" not "Minimized".